# Protecting SSL/TLS session keys into secure device/memory

Tags: openssl

Is it possible to protect the OpenSSL SSL/TLS session keys generated during handshake into some secure device or memory?

I have some basic information about OpenSSL Dynamic Engine, and have written a small proof of concept code to protect the RSA private key using dynamic engine.

But I'm not able to understand how to use dynamic engine to protect the session keys. Is it possible at all?